# How to test for empty arg in this Powershell function

Tags: powershell

This doesn't work :

```
  function test {
    if(($($args[0]) -eq "")) {
      Write-Host "empty"
    }
  }
```

When I type test I don't get "empty"

Comment: Why using args in a function when you can use params and have attributes to ensure the values are correctly set? `[Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]`

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're checking if the first argument is equal to a string that is empty, which can be a valid argument. I think you should check for null, for the case, that there is no argument at all.

```
function test {
    if($null -eq $($args)) {
        Write-Host "empty"
    }
}
```

Comment: In general, in a comparison with ```$null```, the ```$null``` should go on the left of the operator to ensure a *scalar* comparison - see the documentation for a PSScriptAnalyzer rule that looks for this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/utility-modules/psscriptanalyzer/rules/possibleincorrectcomparisonwithnull?view=ps-modules

Comment: Nice, but `$($args)` should be `$args` - no need to wrap a variable reference in `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--)